# Preconditioning before asking a favor

Tags: decision-making

Suppose I want to borrow an item, such as a phone charger from someone.

Instead of directly asking them, "Could I borrow a charger?"

I first ask this question: "Do you have a charger?"

The act of asking a question of fact (whether they have the item or not) will make them more willing to lend you the item.

Is there a term or explanation for this?

Is this related or similar to the Ben Franklin effect and Anchoring effect?

Answer (score 2):

The effect you ask about could very well be seen as an example of the Ben Franklin effect, also known as the foot-in-the-door phenomenon.
In your example, replying to the question "Do you have a charger?" would be interpreted as a small favor which is then followed by the bigger favor of lending the item.

Reference:

Beaman, A. L., Cole, C. M., Preston, M., Klentz, B., & Steblay, N. M. (1983). Fifteen Years of Foot-in-the Door Research. *Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin*, 9(2), 181-196.
DOI: [10.1177/0146167283092002](https://doi.org/10.1177/0146167283092002)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE  Where possible it is preferred if you can provide a DOI or PMID number and link for easy retrieval of articles referenced so I helped out by adding it to your reference